# CDI Producer and Injection

Tags: java, cdi, weld

i want to use a producer in my application but i'm stuck at the point, where i'm trying to inject the bean. im getting the famous WELD-001409 error. please lighten up my understanding of cdi producer.

here's my interface:

```
@Named
    public interface MessageSender {
      void sendMessage();
    }
```

the bean:

```
public class EmailMessageSender implements MessageSender {

  @Override
  public void sendMessage() {
    System.out.println("Sending email message");
  }

}
```

and the producer:

```
@SessionScoped
public class MessageSenderFactory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5269302440619391616L;

    @Produces
    public MessageSender getMessageSender() {
        return new EmailMessageSender();
    }

}
```

now i'm injecting the bean:

```
@Inject 
MessageSender messageSender;
```

when i'm trying to deploy the project i get the WELD-001409 error and eclipse also is saying that there are multiple injection points.

it works with explicit naming:

```
@Inject @Named("messageSender")
MessageSender messageSender;
```

is this naming neccessary?

Comment: On a side note - specify the Java exception class instead of the implementation specific `WELD-001409` since: 1. some people may know CDI but not necessarily WELD, maybe OWB instead; 2. even most people who work with WELD will probably remember the full and descriptive name of the Java exception class but not the cryptic and meaningless `WELD-001409`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your `EmailMessageSender` class implements `MessageSender` and therefore it is a bean available for injection with type either `EmailMessageSender` or `MessageSender`.
2. Your producer returns a bean of type `MessageSender`.
3. Your injection point wants *the only bean in the whole application whose type and qualifiers exactly match the type and qualifiers of the injection point*.

From one and two you have 2 beans that match a single injection point - therefore that's an ambiguous dependency.

Bottom line, your producer is absolutely pointless (aside from causing the error) in the above example because it simply returns a new instance of `EmailMessageSender` which is the same exact effect as simply `@Inject MessageSender` since `EmailMessageSender` has the default scope `@Dependent`.

Comment: Ahhh...thanks for clarifying that. i should have read the tutorial to the end.