# Using a CDI producer causes ambiguous dependencies exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a requirement to Inject the same instance of an `ApplicationScoped` bean into several places of my application and have created the following factory class which uses the `@PostConstruct` annotation to initialize the bean and the `@Produces` annotation to return the same instance of the bean.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CommandBusFactory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private CommandBus commandBus;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        commandBus = new BasicCommandBus();
        // Do some stuff to configure the command bus
    }

    @Produces
    public CommandBus produceCommandBus() {
        return commandBus;
    }

}
```

The problem I've got is when I deploy the application GlassFish returns the following error message:

```
Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [CommandBus] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private myapp.web.ToDoItemCommandController.commandBus]. Possible dependencies [[Producer Method [CommandBus] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces public myapp.core.cdi.CommandBusFactory.produceCommandBus()], Managed Bean [class myapp.core.commandhandling.BasicCommandBus] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]]]
```

I can overcome this exception by adding the `@Alternative` annotation to the BasicCommandBus class, however this doesn't seem to be the best way of solving the problem.

I don't want to add a qualifier everywhere that I inject `CommandBus` into my application as using a different implementation of `CommandBus` would require changing the code in multiple places. The intention is that a later version of the factory will read a configuration file and depending upon a value in the configuration file it may create a different type of `CommandBus`.

I have read the answer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18782027/1274662) and understand why the Ambiguous dependencies exception is being thrown but what I don't know is the best way to deal with the fact that there are two possible beans that could be injected given that I want to decide which implementation is used and how it is initialised in a central location.

The questions I've got are:

1. Is using the `@Alternative` annotation on the `BasicCommandBus` class the right approach?
2. Is there a better approach that I should be using to Inject the same instance of an `ApplicationScoped` bean (i.e. `CommandBus`) into several places of my application whilst controlling which implementation created (i.e. `BasicCommandBus` or `EnhancedCommandBus`) and how it is initialised in a central location?

Comment: Are you sure that your CommandBusFactory does not appear multiple times in your deployed application? Say both in the EAR/lib directory and a WAR/WEB-INF/lib directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your bean to be injectable only by the producer you can annotate `BasicCommandBus` and `EnhancedCommandBus` with `@Vetoed` this way you'll not have the ambiguity between the bean it self and the producer method and at every injection point it's the producer that will inject the instance.